# Operand should contain 1column(s)

Tags: mysql

```
select (select sc_machid as ClinicID,
case
    when substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BB0' then 'Head Office' 
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BA0' THEN 'HeadOffice'
    when substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BA1' THEN 'Villiers'
    when substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BA2' then 'Imperial IDC'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BA3' THEN 'Warden'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BA4' THEN 'Harrismith'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BA5' THEN 'Tugela'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BA6' THEN 'MooiRiver'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='bad' THEN 'MooiRiver'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BB0' THEN 'Port Elizabeth'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BB1' THEN 'East London'
    when substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BB2' THEN 'Umthatha'
    when substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BB3' then 'Kokstad'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BB4' THEN 'Marian Hill'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BB5' THEN 'Zeerust'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BC0' THEN 'Imperial SBD'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BC1' THEN 'Imperial TSD'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BC2' THEN 'Roodekop'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BD0' THEN 'Ventersburg'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BD1' THEN 'Colesburg'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BD2' THEN 'Hanover'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BD3' THEN 'Beaufort West'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BD4' THEN 'Beit Bridge Border Post Musina'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BD5' THEN 'Cape Town - Epping'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BD7' THEN 'Komati Poort'
    end as ClinicName, count(TransactionType) as NumberOfFirstTimePatientVisits
    from sc_audit 
    where TransactionType = 'Insert Patient Record' 
    group by ClinicName)
as t1,
(
    select pat_id as PatientID,
    count(*) as NumberOfVisits,
    sc_clinicid as ClinicID,
    CASE
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BA0' THEN 'HeadOffice'
        when sc_clinicid = 'BA1' THEN 'Villiers'
        when sc_clinicid = 'BA2' then 'Imperial IDC'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BA3' THEN 'Warden'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BA4' THEN 'Harrismith'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BA5' THEN 'Tugela'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BA6' THEN 'MooiRiver'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'bad' THEN 'MooiRiver'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BB0' THEN 'Port Elizabeth'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BB1' THEN 'East London'
        when sc_clinicid = 'BB2' THEN 'Umthatha'
        when sc_clinicid = 'BB3' then 'Kokstad'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BB4' THEN 'Marian Hill'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BB5' THEN 'Zeerust'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BC0' THEN 'Imperial SBD'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BC1' THEN 'Imperial TSD'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BC2' THEN 'Roodekop'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BD0' THEN 'Ventersburg'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BD1' THEN 'Colesburg'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BD2' THEN 'Hanover'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BD3' THEN 'Beaufort West'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BD4' THEN 'Beit Bridge Border Post Musina'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BD5' THEN 'Cape Town - Epping'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BD7' THEN 'Komati Poort'
    end as ClinicName 
    from sc_queue 
    group by ClinicName
) 
as t2;
```

The above query gives me an error that says

```
Operand should contain 1column(s)
```

Please help me, I cant seem to figure out where the problem is

Comment: It looks like your inner select should be the parameter to the first select's from, not the column to select.

Comment: what kind of Query this is?

Comment: You really should create a [function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html) for those 2 case statements, assuming they should actually be the same. Also, you can say `CASE sc_clinicid WHEN ...` and remove `sc_clinicid =` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The subquery `SELECT sc_machid as ClinicID, ...` yields three columns (`ClinicID`, `ClinicName`, `NumberOfFirstTimePatientVisits`). Therefore, it cannot be part of a `SELECT` expression. It must be part of the `FROM` clause. Do it like this:

```
SELECT t1.ClinicID, t1.ClinicName, t1.NumberOfFirstTimePatientVisits
FROM (SELECT sc_machid as ClinicID, ... ) as t1 ...
```

Same goes for `select  pat_id as PatientID,count(*) as NumberOfVisits ...`. Combine these two using

```
SELECT
    t1.ClinicID, t1.ClinicName, t1.NumberOfFirstTimePatientVisits,
    t2.PatientID, t2.NumberOfVisits, t2.ClinicID, t2.ClinicName
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            sc_machid AS ClinicID,
            CASE
                WHEN SUBSTRING (sc_machid,1,3)='BB0' THEN 'Head Office'
                -- ...
            END AS ClinicName,
            COUNT(TransactionType) AS NumberOfFirstTimePatientVisits
        FROM sc_audit 
        WHERE TransactionType = 'Insert Patient Record' 
        GROUP BY ClinicName
    ) AS t1,
    (
        SELECT
            pat_id AS PatientID,
            count(*) AS NumberOfVisits,
            sc_clinicid AS ClinicID,
            CASE
                WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BA0' THEN 'HeadOffice'
                -- ...
            END AS ClinicName
        FROM sc_queue
    ) AS t2
```

A subquery can only be part of a `SELECT` expression, if it returns a single record with a single column. If it returns a single record with multiple columns, you will get the error

> #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: Note that this only fixes your syntax errors. I guess you also want to add a `WHERE` condition `t1.ClinicID = t2.ClinicID`.

Answer (score 0):

Your column t2 is returning more than one records `PatientID, NumberOfVisits, sc_clinicid....` which is not allowed. you can add only 1 column in your inner query when you are adding that query as column result.

Check this fiddle i have tried to inact your error in the query **[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/9367)**

Answer (score 0):

In t2 you are selecting more than one columns and then assigning alias to that which is wrong. Try selecting one column it will work. The problem is you are selecting multiple columns as one column.

```
select (select sc_machid as ClinicID,
case
    when substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BB0' then 'Head Office' 
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BA0' THEN 'HeadOffice'
    when substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BA1' THEN 'Villiers'
    when substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BA2' then 'Imperial IDC'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BA3' THEN 'Warden'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BA4' THEN 'Harrismith'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BA5' THEN 'Tugela'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BA6' THEN 'MooiRiver'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='bad' THEN 'MooiRiver'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BB0' THEN 'Port Elizabeth'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BB1' THEN 'East London'
    when substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BB2' THEN 'Umthatha'
    when substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BB3' then 'Kokstad'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BB4' THEN 'Marian Hill'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BB5' THEN 'Zeerust'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BC0' THEN 'Imperial SBD'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BC1' THEN 'Imperial TSD'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BC2' THEN 'Roodekop'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BD0' THEN 'Ventersburg'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BD1' THEN 'Colesburg'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BD2' THEN 'Hanover'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BD3' THEN 'Beaufort West'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BD4' THEN 'Beit Bridge Border Post Musina'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BD5' THEN 'Cape Town - Epping'
    WHEN substring(sc_machid,1,3)='BD7' THEN 'Komati Poort'
    end as ClinicName, count(TransactionType) as NumberOfFirstTimePatientVisits
    from sc_audit 
    where TransactionType = 'Insert Patient Record' 
    group by ClinicName)
as t1,
(
    CASE
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BA0' THEN 'HeadOffice'
        when sc_clinicid = 'BA1' THEN 'Villiers'
        when sc_clinicid = 'BA2' then 'Imperial IDC'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BA3' THEN 'Warden'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BA4' THEN 'Harrismith'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BA5' THEN 'Tugela'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BA6' THEN 'MooiRiver'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'bad' THEN 'MooiRiver'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BB0' THEN 'Port Elizabeth'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BB1' THEN 'East London'
        when sc_clinicid = 'BB2' THEN 'Umthatha'
        when sc_clinicid = 'BB3' then 'Kokstad'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BB4' THEN 'Marian Hill'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BB5' THEN 'Zeerust'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BC0' THEN 'Imperial SBD'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BC1' THEN 'Imperial TSD'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BC2' THEN 'Roodekop'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BD0' THEN 'Ventersburg'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BD1' THEN 'Colesburg'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BD2' THEN 'Hanover'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BD3' THEN 'Beaufort West'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BD4' THEN 'Beit Bridge Border Post Musina'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BD5' THEN 'Cape Town - Epping'
        WHEN sc_clinicid = 'BD7' THEN 'Komati Poort'
    end as ClinicName 
    from sc_queue 
    group by ClinicName
) 
as t2,
(select pat_id as PatientID,        
    from sc_queue 
    group by ClinicName) as t3,
(select count(*) as NumberOfVisits,        
    from sc_queue 
    group by ClinicName) as t4,
(select sc_clinicid as ClinicID,        
    from sc_queue 
    group by ClinicName) as t5;
```